# How to find specific duplicate words in each cell of a column in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have the following code that works great, and finds any duplicate words in each cell of a column and shows them in another offset cell.

However, what I would like to do if search on specific words only - as shown in the **DuplicateWords** String.

How can I adapt this VBA code to only find duplicates of these **specific** words in each cell within the column and show the output in the offset column?

```
Sub FindDuplicates()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim WordArr As Variant
Dim DubStr As String
Dim WordCount As Integer

Set WS = ActiveSheet

Dim DuplicateWords As String
    DuplicateWords = "Telephone call,Seen by team"

'Loop cells
For i = 1 To WS.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Split cell words into array
    WordArr = Split(WS.Cells(i, 9).Value, " ")
    
    'Loop through each word in cell
    For j = LBound(WordArr) To UBound(WordArr)
        WordCount = 0

        'Count the occurrences of the word
        For k = LBound(WordArr) To UBound(WordArr)
            If UCase(WordArr(j)) = UCase(WordArr(k)) Then
                WordCount = WordCount + 1
            End If
        Next k

        'Output duplicate words to string
        If WordCount > 1 And InStr(1, DubStr, WordArr(j)) = 0 Then
            DubStr = DubStr & WordArr(j) & " "
        End If
    Next j

    'Paste string in column B
    WS.Cells(i, 15).Value = Trim(DubStr)
    DubStr = ""
    Erase WordArr
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to find and return *Telephone call* and *Seen by team*? These are not single words if the comma is supposed to be the delimiter. Please do clarify.

Comment: Correct. It's needs to look for "Telephone call" or "Seen by team", and they could be amongst other words, so it will need a wild card either side. The comma would be the delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub FindDuplicates()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range, v, w, n As Long, sDups
    Dim DuplicateWords
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'terms to check for
    DuplicateWords = Split("Telephone call,Seen by team,email", ",")
    
    For Each c In ws.Range("I1:I" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then                'any cell content?
            sDups = ""                    'clear duplicates
            For Each w In DuplicateWords  'loop terms to look for
                'count the term in the cell text
                n = (Len(v) - Len(Replace(v, w, "", 1, , vbTextCompare))) / Len(w)
                If n > 1 Then 'replicated?
                    sDups = sDups & IIf(sDups <> "", ";", "") & _
                                    w & " (" & n & ")"
                End If
            Next w
            c.EntireRow.Cells(15).Value = sDups
        End If 'cell not blank
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Retrieve Substrings

[image]

```vb
Sub RetrieveSubStrings()
    
    Const SUBSTRING_LIST As String _
        = "Telephone call,Seen by team"
    Const SRC_DELIMITER As String = ","
    Const DST_DELIMITER As String = ","
    
    Dim Substrings() As String: 
    Substrings = Split(SUBSTRING_LIST, SRC_DELIMITER)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim srg As Range:
    Set srg = ws.Range("I2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim sData(): sData = srg.Value
        
    Dim dData() As String: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim Substring, r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For Each Substring In Substrings
            If InStr(1, CStr(sData(r, 1)), Substring, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                If Len(dData(r, 1)) = 0 Then
                    dData(r, 1) = Substring
                Else
                    dData(r, 1) = dData(r, 1) & DST_DELIMITER & Substring
                End If
            End If
        Next Substring
    Next r
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.EntireRow.Columns("O")
    
    drg.Value = dData
    
    MsgBox "Substrings retrieved.", vbInformation

End Sub
```